# Minimum weight for $90\%$ of population.

Tags: probability, statistics

In fish processing plant, after fish are brought from sea, they are made into blocks of “about”$ 10 kg$ each. Then these  blocks are frozen in blast freezers, and sent to customers. Customers thaw blocks at their end. 
Weight loss occurs at two stages viz. freezing and thawing. 
Randomly chosen $100$ blocks of fish (of single/uniform grade) were observed for freezing loss at fish processing plant.

Customer sent observations of randomly chosen $100$ blocks (of same grade as that at fish processing plant) for thawing loss.

Following are the observations

```
Weight loss in freezing Average:              1%       ||        Std dev : 0.25%  
Weight loss in thawing (drip loss) Average:   4%       ||        Std dev : 0.50%
```

Fish blocks are prepared in batches. $1000$ blocks per batch.
Question :  After thawing, weight of fish block should be at least  $10 \ kg$. What should be minimum weight (wet weight/fresh weight) of fish blocks so that no more than $10\%$ of thawed fish blocks are found to be short weight  (i.e. less than $10 \ kg$) by customer. Total number of blocks $10,000$.

**a)**  Assume there is no correlation (zero correlation) between freezing loss and thawing loss.

**b)**  Assume there is perfect correlation $(1$  correlation) between freezing loss and thawing loss.
How to go about it ?

I have tried to solve it in following way. I am not sure it is correct way.

**Step 1.**

```
               Average (%)      Standard deviation (%) 
Freezing loss       1.0           0.25 
 Thawing loss       4.0           0.5
```

**Step 2.**

Calculate 95% confidence limit for population mean for both; freezing loss and thawing loss.

```
             Lower Confidence Limit          Upper Confidence Limit
Freezing loss       0.951                      1.049
Thawing loss        3.902                      4.098
```

**Step 3.**

Calculate 90th percentile for both by presuming UCL as mean (liberal attitude)

```
                 Freezing loss %      Thawing loss %
90th percentile    1.36939               4.739
```

**Step 4.**

```
Target weight after thawing is (min) 10.0 kg

10.00   thawed weight
10.50   frozen weight  (dividing 10 by (1-0.0136939)
10.643  fresh weight (dividing 10.5 by (1-0.04739))
```

**Answer** :

Thus, minimum weight (wet weight/fresh weight) of fish blocks so that no more than $10\%$ of thawed fish blocks are found to be short weight  (i.e. less than $10 \ kg$) by customer is $10.643 \ kg$.  I have not taken into account correlation in this solution.

Is the answer correct? If not, what are corrections?

Comment: Freezing loss: average 1%, standard deviation 0.25%. Thawing loss: average 4%, standard deviation o.50%.   I wonder why "Average(%) Standard deviation(%)" appears as heading.

Comment: Correction: at 'Step 3'  phrase '90th percentile' is probably wrong.  Correct phrase should be like 'random variable (i.e. weight loss percentage) appearing at 90th percent of population'.